# Clear browser cache only on logout

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I clear browser cache only on logout, sure I can use the below:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

But this particular page which is a shopping bag page is accessible by both login and non-login users. How can I set it in such a way whereby the login user is able to access this page without clearing the browser cache but **Only** clears it when he/she logs out so that another user will not be able to access the history contents.

I have tried the solutions here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/135121/Browser-back-button-issue-after-logout
made some changes but still couldn't figure out how to deal with this issue.

I also cleared my session on logout as below but I understand the browser cache will still stay.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
Response.Redirect("~/");
```

Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not a c# expert, but I am pretty sure what you have above only tells the browser to not cache the page you are on. There is no way to tell the browser to clear cache on any page. This would be a problem if there was such a way. Sounds like the solution you need is to not cache any page at all, regardless of logging out or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but any idea what kind of techniques should I use deal with my situation as mentioned?

Comment: You can control what the browser does! The caching stuff is only a hint at what the browser should do. I can make a browser that caches everything. I think the solution is to only allow logged in users access the product page and non-logged in users get redirected. Then of course don't cache anything. This is how many websites do it.

Comment: @Amir Think you meant "You can't control"?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. Can't control.  Too late to edit it.

Comment: I can't redirect Non-logged in users as they need to access the cart page too, even without registering, they can place stuff in the shopping cart.

Comment: Right? I still don't see what your problem is. Redirect when they click checkout. You have to have them sign in at some time. Amazon does what you are saying. They use sessions to keep track of you cart and when you want to checkout they force to sign it.

Comment: My apology if I haven't made this clear, "They use sessions to keep track of you cart and when you want to checkout they force to sign it.", yes this is what mine is doing as well, but maybe I haven't realise what I am doing wrong because the user upon logging off is able to access the previous pages and access the cart history.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are getting muddled with the difference between server and client cache?

If you set [output cache](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308375) on your aspx page, that's server-side cache, and you have a scenario where .NET can decide whether to send pre-cached content or not, and still apply ACL rules.

If you set cache requirements on the HTTP you return using `Response.Cache`, that's client-side caching. Once the browser obeys the cache rules you send here, the only opportunity you will have to retract your cache rules is the next time the browser requests the page. If you set the cache to expire tomorrow, that's the next chance you'll get to amend the caching. Assuming the browser is obeying you, by the way, of which there is no guarantee.

In short, dynamic pages should not attempt to set client-side caching if you want them to stay dynamic. In fact you should actively use techniques such as the ones you mentioned to suppress Caching on those pages at all times.

Client-side caching should really only be used to assist with performance and bandwidth on the static parts of your site.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve a similar problem myself. This is just speculation, but if i could track a user specific header in my requests I was going to try using

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["login"] = true;
```

in the global.asax

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "login")
    {
        return User().Name;
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it.  If you are caching a page, you can add a vary parameter.  For Example

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "random")]
[CompressFilter]
public ActionResult Page(PageModel model)
{
      ...
}
```

In the example above, if I pass a random variable like the ticks of the current datetime object, that will prevent the cache.